# Relationship between RSSI or throughput with encryption

Tags: wireless

I am trying to find out performance of my Wireless Sensor Network interms of RSSI and Throughput. I want to know whether there is any relationship between RSSI or throughput measurement with encryption? I mean will RSSI or throughput show different result if I change the encryption method or key size of the encryption I am using in this WSN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSSI is a measure of relative signal strength at the receiver.  The transmitter power does not change with the encryption method, so RSSI should not change.

Virtually all Wifi devices manufactured in the last several years employ hardware encryption, so there's no throughput impact, assuming you're using WEP, WPA or WPA2.

RSSI and throughout are related, in the sense that low RSSI values mean low signal levels, which in turn increase transmission errors and therefore retransmits, that lower overall throughput.

Comment: Do any WiFi devices offer AES that's handled by an ASIC? I can imagine that would eliminate a big portion of any limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption with RSN adds a overhead of ~16 bytes per frame.  This is negligible in a ~1500 byte frame, and is even more negligible considering that with current 802.11 modulations, the coordination function (CSMA/CA) becomes a major overhead.

Most encryption is done in hardware directly on the wireless module (most CPU would have trouble running AES at 300 mbps) so enabling encryption should have no other bottleneck.

However, enabling WEP disables 802.11n, so reduces the throughput.